# date_format() equivalent in BigQuery

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

I have a date column in my table that contains a string in the format 2017-08-05 09-AM, and I'm trying to format it so that there is a column Date with a date type and  column Time with a time type.

```
SELECT ID, DATE_FORMAT(a.date, "%Y-%d-%m") as date, DATE_FORMAT(a.date, "%T") as time, Symbol
FROM `crypto_market_data.BTC_1H` a
ORDER BY ID
```

The query runs how I want it to in MySQL, but date_format() is not supported in BigQuery. I'm wondering if there is a similar way to cast my string date to a separate Date and Time object.

Comment: Do you specifically need separate date and time columns? BigQuery has a `DATETIME` type that combines `DATE` and `TIME` (see the `PARSE_DATETIME` function). Storage is cheaper for one column versus two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id, Symbol,
  DATE(PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %H-%p', a.date)) AS `date`,
  TIME(PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %H-%p', a.date)) AS time
FROM `project.dataset.table` a
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, '2017-08-05 09-AM' `date`, 'x' Symbol UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2019-02-05 12-AM', 'y' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, '2019-01-31 11-PM', 'z'
)
SELECT id, Symbol,
  DATE(PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %H-%p', a.date)) AS `date`,
  TIME(PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %H-%p', a.date)) AS time
FROM `project.dataset.table` a
-- ORDER BY id
```

with result

```
Row id  Symbol  date        time     
1   1   x       2017-08-05  09:00:00     
2   2   y       2019-02-05  12:00:00     
3   3   z       2019-01-31  11:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `PARSE_DATETIME` function available for parsing custom datetime formats in BigQuery.

In your case, this should help:

```
select ID, extract(date from dt) as date, extract(time from dt) as time, Symbol from (
  select 
     a.ID as ID, 
     parse_datetime('%Y-%d-%m %H-%p', a.date) as dt, 
     a.Symbol as Symbol
  from 
     `crypto_market_data.BTC_1H` a
  order by a.ID
)
```

Comment: Just tried this and got error: Failed to parse input string "2019-02-05 12-AM"

Comment: Hmm... I actually got your parse_datetime() to work as a one-liner using `SELECT parse_datetime('%Y-%d-%m %H-%p', "2019-02-05 12-AM");` but when I changed the time to "2019-01-31 11-PM" the same one-liner gave me the error mentioned above

Comment: Use `'%Y-%d-%m %H-%p'` if you want to put date before month, else use `'%Y-%m-%d %H-%p'` if you want to use month prior to date. In your second date, month is placed where the date is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT ID, FORMAT_DATE("%Y-%d-%m",a.date) as date, FORMAT_DATE("%T",a.date) as time, Symbol FROM` crypto_market_data.BTC_1H `a ORDER BY ID`

Bigquery uses the FORMAT_DATE For more info, follow this link [BIG QUERY DATE FUNCTIONS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions)